# SSMTP can't establish a startssl connection from a Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux, email, raspberry-pi, smtp, ssmtp

I'm trying to set up automated e-mails on my raspberry pi, but it won't negotiate a STARTTLS session.

The ssmtp.conf is as follows -

```
root=postmaster
mailhub={mailserver}:587
AuthUser={username}
AuthPass={password}
UseTLS=TES
UseSTARTTLS=YES
hostname={hostname}
FromLineOverride=YES
DEBUG=YES
```

No revaliases.
The error I get in mail.err is as follows -

```
sSMTP[13572]: Cannot open {mailserver}:587
```

In syslog I get the following lines -

```
sSMTP[13119]: Creating SSL connection to host
sSMTP[13119]: 220 {mailserver} ESMTP Postfix
sSMTP[13119]: EHLO {hostname}
sSMTP[13119]: 250 DSN
sSMTP[13119]: STARTTLS
sSMTP[13119]: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
sSMTP[13119]: SSL connection using (null)
sSMTP[13119]: Cannot open {mailserver}:587
```

And it just dies. I've tried tweaking the hostname parameter, the UseTLS and UseSTARTTLS parameters, didn't work. I also tried setting TLS_CA_File and TLS_CA_Dir parameters advertised in similar (but old) forum posts but these don't even seem to work at all -

```
sSMTP[13572]: Unable to set TLS_CA_Dir="/etc/ssl/certs/"
```

and

```
sSMTP[12962]: Unable to set TLS_CA_FILE="/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt"
```

Server side I get this -

```
postfix/submission/smtpd[7557]: warning: dict_nis_init: NIS domain name not set - NIS lookups disabled
postfix/submission/smtpd[7557]: connect from unknown[{ip}]
postfix/submission/smtpd[7557]: SSL_accept error from unknown[{ip}]: -1
postfix/submission/smtpd[7557]: warning: TLS library problem: error:140760FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_CLIENT_HELLO:unknown protocol:s23_srvr.c:649:
postfix/submission/smtpd[7557]: lost connection after STARTTLS from unknown[{ip}]
postfix/submission/smtpd[7557]: disconnect from unknown[{ip}]
```

However everything works fine when I try the same config on a Ubuntu 18.04 machine or from desktop e-mail clients such as Thunderbird. Any ideas on why it won't connect to the server from the Pi?

Comment: Do you have generated the `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` file?

Comment: Yup, but it doesn't seem to matter since ssmtp doesn't let me set the TLS_CA_FILE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ssmtp is unmaintained software and has known TLS-related problems. Debian [completely removed](https://tracker.debian.org/news/956307/ssmtp-removed-from-testing/) ssmtp from repositories several months ago, Ubuntu will follow.

The only reason it works in Ubuntu/Debian is because [Debian used to apply a patch](https://sources.debian.org/patches/ssmtp/2.64-8/01-374327-use-gnutls.patch/) (which ports ssmtp to GnuTLS for licensing reasons, and fortuitously solves the bugs that the original code had).

(In your case, I would *guess* that the error is caused by the client sending the outdated "SSLv2-compatible" ClientHello message, which is way past its useful date and which is no longer recognized by OpenSSL on the Postfix server.)

The ability to use `TLS_CA_*` parameters is another patch added by Debian – the original ssmtp software doesn't have these options because it performs [no certificate validation](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=662960) at all.

Use msmtp instead.

Comment: Too bad one can only find this extremely helpful answer after stumbling upon other posts recommending to specify `TLS_CA_File` as a solution for errors like `Invalid response SMTP server` and `Cannot open smtp.xyz.ab:465`. To hopefully save others some time, here is an instruction I found particularly useful when configuring `msmtp`: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Msmtp#Test_functionality